# How to know if a certain timestamp exists in a postgres table cell

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timezone

There is a postgres table that has timestamp with time zone (format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.pppp' table as the primary key. I want to check if a certain timestamp (without time zone) exists in the postgres table.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC ('minute', time_stamp) at time zone tz_name as time_stamp
from table_name WHERE time_stamp at
time zone tz_name = TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-25 09:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

However it returns nothing. However, when I query an interval it will return the values. The following query returns the timestamps greater than the specified value:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC ('minute', time_stamp) at time zone tz_name as time_stamp
from table_name WHERE time_stamp at
time zone tz_name >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-25 09:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

How to go about finding if a timestamp exists in the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use this:

```
select * 
from mytable_time
where to_char(datec,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') = '2019-02-11 18:15'
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=df01b4627dcbae4252ebdf6a9f1f0f51) that show's you how two different columns work : timestamp and date columns. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @bhumika53, would appreciate your feedback, does this work ?

Comment: Yes it works. The following is also works. The difference is that your method compares by converting into strings, whereas the following is comparing the timestamps.                                                                          `SELECT DATE_TRUNC ('minute', time_stamp) at time zone tz_name as time_stamp  FROM table_name
WHERE
DATE_TRUNC ('minute', time_stamp) at time zone tz_name = TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-25 09:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`

Comment: I do not know why should you do that. One side is string, other one is not, so it is better to do only one conversion. I believe you will find my method faster... Try it out...